# How to close a tab from code behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to close current tab from code behind as i want to perform some operation so after performing some operation it should be closed so please help me.. thanks in advance.

I tried it with

```
function close_window() {
  if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
    close();
  }
}
```

but not able to call this method from code behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    string jScript;
    jScript="<script>close_window();</script>";
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"keyClientBlock", jScript);
```

Comment: It Shows That this method is obsolete as i am using .net 3.5 so Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("keyClienntBlock",jscript); wont work

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I thought I would post what worked for me. Tested and working in .NET 3.5 & 4.0.

```
Response.Write("<script>window.close();</script>");
```